# How to give objects to someone?

Tags: scribblenauts-unlimited

Seriously, I'm stuck here:
[image]

I've tried almost every sort of command to "drop" the `sponge` on Maxwell and nothing happens.

What this icon actually means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maxwell is the boy with the red cap, not the farmer. The instructions seem a little ambiguous there (and slightly incorrect), but you're just supposed to use it "yourself".

Comment: Hello, Low Quality queue, here I come!

Comment: Haha, Maxwell is a horrible name for a kid, sorry.